# Why c++ can not read recordset from such a stored procedure

Tags: c++, sql-server

I need to read some recordset from sql server stored procedure. The procedure looks very simple, but during read, there is something I can not understand

Stored procedure Version 1:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_cbqueue_pickup_some]
as

create table #tmp 
(
    id bigint
)

insert #tmp (id) 
select top 100 id 
from cbqueue 
where scheduletime<=GETDATE() and [FetchTime] is null

update CBQueue set fetchtime = GETDATE() 
where ID in (select id from #tmp)

select languagesrc,countrysrc,operatorsrc 
from cbqueue 
where id in (select id from #tmp)
```

and this is my c++ code to read recordset:

```
try{
    _CommandPtr pCommand = NULL;

TBX_TICK curTick = TBX_GET_TICK_PRECISE();
if (mpConn == NULL)
    Connect();
else if (((curTick - mLastOperation) / 1000) > 30)
{
    Disconnect();
    Connect();
}
mLastOperation = curTick;

pCommand.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
pCommand->ActiveConnection = mpConn;
pCommand->CommandText = (_bstr_t)"sp_cbqueue_pickup_some";
pCommand->CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;
pCommand->CommandTimeout = miCommandTimeout;

int n = 0;
_RecordsetPtr pRecordset = NULL;

pRecordset = pCommand->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdStoredProc);

while(!(pRecordset->EndOfFile))
{
    buffer[n].Index = pRecordset->Fields->GetItem("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")->GetValue().intVal;
    buffer[n].ANI = (char*)((_bstr_t)(pRecordset->Fields->GetItem("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy")->GetValue()));
    buffer[n].DEST = (char*)((_bstr_t)(pRecordset->Fields->GetItem("zzzzzzzzzzzz")->GetValue()));
    n++;
    if (n >= length)
        break;
    pRecordset->MoveNext();
 }
}

catch (_com_error &e) {
}
```

in this situation, when code step to this statement:

```
while(!(pRecordset->EndOfFile))
```

program will jump to the catch block

but if I change the stored procedure to this form:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_cbqueue_pickup_some]
as
select languagesrc,countrysrc,operatorsrc from cbqueue
```

the c++ code will not happen exception again, I spend much time to find this change can remove the exception, but I still not know what is the reason. 
Could anyone figure me out?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Well if both your c++ code and your stored procedure work when run separately, that means the problem is not there, I would try to concentrate on the library or driver you are using to connect to the SQL server, looks to me this library is having some problems understanding your SQL

Comment: the exception is "can not read memory"

Comment: You shouldn't prefix your procedures with sp_. It has a special meaning and is meant for system procedures